# Dump MySQL database into a new database on another server

Tags: ssh, mysql, mysqlimport

I wanted to get a second opinion on the below.

What i'm trying to achieve is to dump a mysql database over to a new database on a different server, I also wanted to do it with limited write to the original server.

The plan is to dump the old mysql database, and import the output into the new database on the second server.

Here is what i've got, I've done it this way so that in theory the original server will only be doing a read, where as the new server will be doing the write.

```
mysqldump -uAUSER -p'APASS' dbname | ssh user@newhost mysql -uAUser -p'APASS' newdbname
```

Thanks!

Comment: that should work fine although it the db dump is big ftp/sftp it probably a better option (although it would require write on the source server)

Comment: Maybe include the -C option to ssh, to speed up the copy to the server (since the dump file is text)

Comment: Thanks Guys, @dsummersl I added -C. I've kicked it off and it seems to be quite happy.

Comment: I also added -q to mysqldump so that it forces mysqldump to retrieve rows for a table from the server a row at a time rather than retrieving the entire row set and buffering it in memory before writing it out. I added this as I was having an issue with memory.

Comment: -q is good, see this post for more, http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000690.html

Comment: "mysqldump can retrieve and dump table contents row by row, or it can retrieve the entire content from a table and buffer it in memory before dumping it. Buffering in memory can be a problem if you are dumping large tables. To dump tables row by row, use the --quick option (or --opt, which enables --quick). The --opt option (and hence --quick) is enabled by default, so to enable memory buffering, use --skip-quick."

Answer (score 0):

It may work, but it is risky.

I would advise you to mysqldump into a file, copy the file using scp, then `mysql < file` on the target server. That gives you a couple of restart points if anything (like a transfer through the network) fails.

It also gives you a file backup of your db, which might be handy later.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysqldump command to dump data from a live database to a slave database

mysqldump -u [user_name] -h [hostname] --password=[password] [live_db_name] | mysql -u [user_name] -h [hostname] --password=[password] [slave_db_name]